# Making a custom istream manipulator

Tags: c++, io, istream, manipulators

I want to make a custom `istream` manipulator that reads 2 characters from the input, then skips 2 characters from the input, and does that until it runs out of any input.

For example, if I have code like this:

```
std::string str;
std::cin >> skipchar >> str;
```

Where `skipchar` is my manipulator, if the user enters `1122334455`, `str` should contain `113355`.

This is what I've got so far, I don't know what I should put in the while loop condition to make this code work properly:

```
istream& skipchar(istream& stream)
{
    char c;

    while(1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
            stream >> c;

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
            stream.ignore(1, '\0');
    }

    return stream;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very nice question. I don't know if it's possible. But I implemented something different which gives you the same short syntax you wanted, by overloading the `>> operator` with a new class called `Skip2`. Here is the code (which I really enjoyed writing! :-) )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <istream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class Skip2 {
public:
    string s;
};

istream &operator>>(istream &s, Skip2 &sk) 
{
    string str;
    s >> str;

    // build new string
    ostringstream build;
    int count = 0;
    for (char ch : str) {
        // a count "trick" to make skip every other 2 chars concise
        if (count < 2) build << ch;
        count = (count + 1) % 4;
    }

    // assign the built string to the var of the >> operator
    sk.s = build.str();

    // and of course, return this istream
    return s;
}



int main()
{
    istringstream s("1122334455");
    Skip2 skip;

    s >> skip;
    cout << skip.s << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This code is simple and does just what I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

It's tricky; istream manipulators don't operate as "filters" on the stream but rather as single-shot operations. The istream manipulators provided by the Standard (`noskipws`, `hex` etc.) do their work by setting and clearing flags on the stream, so they only expose functionality that is already available.

However, it is possible to create a filtering *streambuf* wrapping the streambuf of `cin` (or any input stream) and use a manipulator to install or remove it:

```
struct skipbuf : std::streambuf {
    std::unique_ptr<std::streambuf> src;
    int i;
    char buf[4];
    skipbuf(std::streambuf* src) : std::streambuf{*src}, src{src} {
        setg(buf, buf + 2, buf + 2);
    }
    std::streambuf* unwrap() {
        while (buf + i != gptr())
            src->sputbackc(buf[--i]);
        return src.release();
    }
    std::streambuf::int_type underflow() override {
        setg(buf, buf, buf + std::min(i = src->sgetn(buf, 4), 2));
        return i ? buf[0] : traits_type::eof();
    }
};

std::istream& skipchar(std::istream& is) {
    is.rdbuf(new skipbuf{is.rdbuf()});
    return is;
}

std::istream& noskipchar(std::istream& is) {
    if (auto* buf = dynamic_cast<skipbuf*>(is.rdbuf()))
        delete (is.rdbuf(buf->unwrap()), buf);
    return is;
}
```

Example of usage:

```
int main() {
    std::istringstream iss{"1122334455   hello"};
    std::string s1, s2;
    iss >> skipchar >> s1 >> noskipchar >> s2;
    std::cout << s1 << ' ' << s2 << std::endl;
}
```

Expected output ([<kbd>run it online</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/77b07308dc16e13e)):

```
113355 hello
```

Comment: That is amazing. Thanks! Wa-a-a-y too advanced for me, but I'll google as much `iostream` stuff as I can in order to understand your code better :)